# Excel copy values from column to column but remove specific text

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm using this code for copying values from Sheet(1) Column A to Sheet(2) Column B. It's working fine and whenever a value in column A is updated column B is also updated.

The problem, or the question I have, is that I want to include one more column in Sheet(1), Column (B). Column B only contains different names, and are not to be copied

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1:A50").Copy Sheets(2).Range("B1")
    End If

End Sub
```

But if column B has the word "SUM" in it it shouldnt copy column A in sheet 1 to Column B in sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Find` to see if 'SUM' is in Sheet(2).Col(b)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng as Range

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50")) Is Nothing Then
    set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B:B").find What:="SUM", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    if rng is nothing then
      Range("A1:A50").Copy Sheets(2).Range("B1")
    end if
    set rng = nothing
  End If

End Sub
```